# Finding average on equal days using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, average

I have a data set, where I'm trying to get an average on days remaining that are equal.
Example:

```
 ship_date    Order_date   cumulative_ordered   days_remaining

 2018-07-01   2018-05-06     7                  56 days
 2018-07-01   2018-05-07     10                 55 days
 2018-07-01   2018-05-08     15                 54 days
```

The order_date will count down until it reaches the ship_date. by that time the cumulative order equals the total orders up until the shipping date. Then a new ship_date and the process repeats. I want to see the percentage average on each day up until the order date. For instance if ship_date 2018-07-01 has a total of 100 orders and ship_date 2018-08-01 has a total of 200, then I want to see how much percentage wise on average was ordered 54 days prior to ship_date.

Thanks.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand. difference_in_days is equal to what?

Comment: `average on days remaining` equal to what? Where is your `days remaining` column?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what was the output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the average of `total_ordered` per `difference_in_days` using [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df.groupby("difference_in_days")['total_ordered'].mean()
```

This returns a Series with the `total_ordered` average per each group of rows with some specific `difference_in_days` for example:

```
difference_in_days
2 days    10.5
56 days   50.22
...
Name: total_ordered, dtype: float64
```

In order to extract one of the mean values from that Series, you need to assign it to a variable and use the index. Say you want the average of `total_ordered` for rows with `difference_in_days` equal to `56`, you should do:

```
g = df.groupby("difference_in_days")['total_ordered'].mean()

# value is the average total_ordered for rows with 56 days of difference.
value = g[g.index.days == 56].iloc[0]
```

Comment: Thanks so much @julianPeller! I changed value to:

     
       'value = g/g[g.index.days == 0].iloc[0]'

This is to get the percentage completed order per date.
I'm then trying to merge this into a new csv file to create a forecast for cumulative_ordered. Any suggestions how to do that, cause what I have tried is not working. I've added 'diff' to the other file and tried to merge on that...